# Хочу вывести на консоль людей, между которыми минимальнок и максимальное растояние с помощью LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
internal class GeoCordinate
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }


    public GeoCordinate(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        Latitude = latitude;
        Longitude = longitude;
    }
}
internal class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public string SecondName;
    public GeoCordinate Location;

    public Person(string name, string secondName, GeoCordinate location)
    {
        Name = name;
        SecondName = secondName;
        Location = location;
    }

    
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person("Vlad", "Pob", new GeoCordinate(-54.32, 84.63)),
            new Person("Oleg", "Berd", new GeoCordinate(3.37, -115.48)),
            new Person("Kiril", "Old", new GeoCordinate(-23.0, 45.89)),
            new Person("Vasya", "Melt", new GeoCordinate(88.7, 2.12)),
            new Person("Stepan", "Valid", new GeoCordinate(34.86, 154.35)),
         };




        //            find out who is located farthest north / south / west / east using latitude/ longitude data
        //find max and min distance between 2 persons
        

        var northiest = list.MaxBy(p => p.Location.Latitude);
        var southiest = list.MinBy(p => p.Location.Latitude);
        var westiest = list.MaxBy(p => p.Location.Longitude);
        var eastier = list.MinBy(p => p.Location.Longitude);

        Console.WriteLine($"Northies:{northiest.Name + " " + northiest.SecondName}" +
            $"\nSouthiest: {southiest.Name + " " + southiest.SecondName}" +
            $"\nEastier: {eastier.Name + " " + eastier.SecondName}" +
            $"\nWestiest: {westiest.Name + " " + westiest.SecondName} ");
                        

        
         
       


    }
}
```

Comment: Вам надо искать расстояние между двумя точками на полоскости, а потом выбирать из них макс и мин. Не надо искать максимальное значение и минимальное  - это не правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

класс

```
internal class GeoCordinate
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public GeoCordinate(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        Latitude = latitude;
        Longitude = longitude;
    }
    public double Distance(GeoCordinate a)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Latitude - a.Latitude, 2) +
               Math.Pow(Longitude - a.Longitude, 2));
    }
}
```

main:

```
    List<Person> list = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person("Vlad", "Pob", new GeoCordinate(-54.32, 84.63)),
        new Person("Oleg", "Berd", new GeoCordinate(3.37, -115.48)),
        ...
    };

    Dictionary<string, double> dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();
    // Ищем расстояние всех со всеми
    for(int x=0; x<list.Count; x++)
    {
        for(int y=x+1; y < list.Count; y++)
        {
            var name = $"{list[x].Name}_{list[x].SecondName} - {list[y].Name}_{list[y].SecondName}";
            dict.Add(name, list[x].Location.Distance(list[y].Location));
        }
    }
    var maxDist = dict.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Value > y.Value ? x : y);
    var minDist = dict.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Value > y.Value ? y : x);
    Console.WriteLine($"Max: {maxDist}\nMin: {minDist}");
```

Вывод:

```
Max: [Oleg_Berd - Stepan_Valid, 271.66127622464]
Min: [Vlad_Pob - Kiril_Old, 49.8169649818212]
```

Вариант с LINQ

```
var pairs = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count - 1)
            let x = list[i]
            from y in list.Skip(i + 1)
            select Tuple.Create(
             $"{x.Name}_{x.SecondName} - {y.Name}_{y.SecondName}",
             x.Location.Distance(y.Location));

            var maxD= pairs.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Item2 > y.Item2 ? x : y);
            var minD = pairs.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Item2 > y.Item2 ? y : x);

            Console.WriteLine($"Max: {maxD}\nMin: {minD}");
```

Вывод:

```
Max: (Oleg_Berd - Stepan_Valid, 271.66127622464)
Min: (Vlad_Pob - Kiril_Old, 49.8169649818212)
```

Что понятнее - решать Вам